# FileNotFoundException and exception handling in Java

Tags: java, file, exception

I made sure to have all the exceptions I think are needed but it keeps giving me this error:

**exception FileNotFoundException has already been caught
catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)**

```
public class SNIDDb
{
  private char delimiter;
  private String name;
  private BufferedReader br;

  public SNIDDb(String name, char delimiter)
  {
    this.name=name;
    this.delimiter=delimiter;
    try
    {
      FileReader fr= new FileReader(name);
      br= new BufferedReader(fr);
    }
    catch(IOException i)
    {
      System.out.println(i.getMessage());
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
    {
      System.out.print(fnfe.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `FileNotFoundException` you will see it is

```
public class FileNotFoundException extends IOException {
```

So by catching the base class `IOException` you are already, in effect, catching the derived exception, hence the error you are seeing.

However, if you further look at the `FileReader` constructor you are calling, it only throws `FileNotFoundException` so you actually don't need to catch `IOException` in and can remove that catch clause and fix your error.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like FileNotFoundException extends IOException. Try inverting the two catch statements and you should be good.

> Class FileNotFoundException
>   java.lang.Object
>   java.lang.Throwable
>   java.lang.Exception
>   java.io.IOException
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html

Comment: Says that the catch IOException is unreachable when I do that

Answer (score 0):

Since FileNotFoundException extends IOException, you can choose either FileNotFoundException or IOException based on your needs.